# Can't set headers after they are sent after building array in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm attempting to build an array of objects and send to client. Receiving error:

```html
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\Dropbox (Personal)\coding\coinTracker5\node_modules\expr                         ess\lib\response.js:725:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\Dropbox (Personal)\coding\coinTracker5\node_modules\expres                         s\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\Dropbox (Personal)\coding\coinTracker5\node_modules\expres                         s\lib\response.js:256:15)
    at D:\Dropbox (Personal)\coding\coinTracker5\routes\index.js:58:11
    at D:\Dropbox (Personal)\coding\coinTracker5\node_modules\cryptox\lib\index.js:51:9
    at D:\Dropbox (Personal)\coding\coinTracker5\node_modules\cryptox\lib\bitfinex.js:93:                         13
    at D:\Dropbox (Personal)\coding\coinTracker5\node_modules\cryptox\lib\bitfinex.js:72:                         13
    at Request._callback (D:\Dropbox (Personal)\coding\coinTracker5\node_modules\bitfinex                         -api-node\rest.js:95:16)
    at Request.self.callback (D:\Dropbox (Personal)\coding\coinTracker5\node_modules\requ                         est\request.js:187:22)
```

I think `res.json(rates)` is only firing once, so I'm not sure why the headers are being set twice?

Also if there is a better way to build this array and send it to client, please enlighten me! Thank you

```js
var rates = [];
for (var i = 0, len = cryptoxArray.length; i < len; i++) {

  cryptoxArray[i].getRate({
    pair: "XBT_USD"
  }, function(err, rateResponse) {
    if (!err)
      rates.push(rateResponse);

    if (i == len) {
      console.log('rates: ' + rates);
      res.json(rates);
    }
  });
```

Comment: the only issue is you are sending response in the array, so every time the loop executes it tries to respond back but can't as it was executed when the loop was run for the first time. Simple solution, finish the execution of loop first and then respond back outside the loop so the response is sent only once.

Answer (score 1):

Your `res.json` is inside your `for` loop. The loop will finish iterating and call `res.json` before the work to fetch rates ever happens. If you are hoping to get all the rates, you will likely need to wait for all the `getRate` calls to finish before responding. I would use promises for this.

```
// if getRate returned a promise
var rates = cryptox.map(item => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  item.getRate({pair:'XBT_USD'}, (err, rate) => {
    if (err) return reject(err);
    return resolve(rate);
  })
})
Promise.all(rates)
  .then(res.json);
```

I realize now that just saying use Promises doesn't help a lot. Here is a non promises version. This is put together on the fly but should work-ish.

```
function mapAsync (fn, list, cb) {
  var newList = [];
  var i = 0;

  function counter (err, value) {
    console.log('count', value)
    if (err) return cb(err);
    newList.push(value);
    if (i === list.length -1) return cb(newList);
    i++;
    callItem();
  }

  function callItem () {
    return fn(list[i], counter)
  }
  return callItem();
}

function getRateFromItem (item, cb) {
  return i.getRate({pair:'XBT_USD'}, cb);
}

mapAsync(getRateFromItem, cryptoxArray, (err, values) => {
  // as long as there is no err you should have your array of values
})
```

Comment: Could you help me understand how to use a promise in this specific case? I have been reading about promises today and can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: getRate returns json like: `{
  "timestamp": "2016-10-16T15:00:07Z",
  "error": "",
  "data": [
    {
      "pair": "EUR_USD",
      "rate": "1.09727328"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: @chuckieDub I don't think SO comments are the place to learn promises. There are tons of resources on the internet for them. Try them out and repost any problems you run into.

Answer (score 1):

by the time any callback is called i will already be equal to length you can't use a loop like this. my suggestion would be use a promisses and do a Promose.all for this or an iife.

iiefe

```
for(i, len, etc){
  (function(index){do your stuff here})(i)
}
```

my personal favorite would be something along these lines.

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';

Promise.all(
 cryptoxArray.map(
   item => Promise.promisify(item. getRate)({pair: "XBT_USD"})
   .then(rate => rate, error => null)
 ) 
)
.then(rates => rates.filter(rate => rate !== null))
.then(res.json);
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why I'm getting this error with that code? `.then(res.json);
                        ^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: as i explained at the beginning of my answer, you are relying on the loop counter inside of your callback to determine when to send the data. the problem is that by the time the first callback is execute i === length --> true for all the callbacks so you will be calling res.json every time a callback is executed on an open connection hence the error. the first time you execute res.json the response headers are set and sent. you can't change them and that is what it will try to do when you do res.json for the second time

Comment: Sorry I meant I tried to use your code instead and received that error.

Comment: which one? the promise or the iife? if is the iife make sure you replace `i` with `index` inside of the iife, since is the local scope variable

Comment: yea i fixed it, i had some missing parenthesis, thats why i said something along those lines? didn't mean it was copy and paste ready ;) but it should work now

Comment: this is giving me a blank array again, but I will continue to research promises. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply use async each to wait all the asynchronous callback before sending the response :

```
var rates = [];
async.each(cryptoxArray, function(e, callback) {

   e.getRate({
    pair: "XBT_USD"
   }, function(err, rateResponse) {
     if (!err){
       rates.push(rateResponse);
     }
     callback();
   });
},

function(err){
   return res.json(rates);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue recently, I was looking for the all the data that belongs to a group of properties that belongs to a parent property and after a day trying different things, found the solution with the follow fragment:

```
Model.find({field: req.params.id})
.then(response1 => {
 let myexpected = response1.map(item => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   Model2.find({field: item._id}, (err, resolveData) => {
    if (err) return reject(err);
    return resolve(resolveData);
   })
 }));
  Promise.all(myexpected)
    .then(expectedData => {
      console.log(expectedData);
      res.status(200).json({data: expectedData});
    })
})
```

I hope that helps you, or helps to another person that looking for a similar solution.

Comment: Could you explain what about this fragment solves the problem?